# Passing a mutable lambda with unique_ptr into a const& std::function

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

I have got a dispatch function which executes a given lambda in a main thread. For the sake of this question, suppose it looks like the following:

```
void dispatch(const std::function<void()>& fn) {
    fn();
}
```

I need to load a new object in a new thread without interrupting the main thread. So I do the following: 1) start a new thread and create a new unique pointer inside the thread, 2) call `dispatch` and propagate the new unique pointer where it belongs.

```
std::unique_ptr<std::string> foo; // nullptr

// do the loading in a new thread:
std::thread t([&](){
    // in the new thread, load new value "Blah" and store it temporarily
    auto bar = std::make_unique<std::string>("Blah");
    dispatch([bar2 = std::move(bar), &foo]() mutable {
        foo = std::move(bar2); // propagate the loaded value to foo
    });
});
t.join(); // for the sake of this example

std::cout << "foo = " << *foo << std::endl; // this should say: foo = Blah
```

Run example online: http://cpp.sh/5zjvm

This code does not compile because the inner lambda in `dispatch` is `mutable` and so does not fit into `dispatch(const std::function<void()>& fn)` which requires a `const&`.

The lambda, however, needs to be `mutable` because it needs to call `std::move` on the unique pointers.

This code could be fixed for example by changing `dispatch` to:

```
template <typename Fn>
void dispatch(Fn fn) {
    fn();
}
```

Unfortunately, the `dispatch` function is an API of a library and I cannot change it.

Is there a way out of this problem without getting rid of unique pointers?

Comment: Why don't you just do `foo = std::make_unique<std::string>("Blah");` inside the thread instead of making `dispatch` the thing that populates `foo`?

Comment: That is a good idea, but I need to prevent race conditions in a real-time rendering application. There is a main thread rendering `foo` (in reality, `foo` is a geometry object, not `std::string`) and I cannot change the value of `foo` in the middle of the rendering. I need to dispatch the new `foo` to the main thread so that it is populated after a previous frame finished being rendered and before a new frame starts being rendered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, that isn't your problem.

Your problem is that your lambda cannot be copied, as it has a unique ptr captured by value in it.

`std::function<Sig>` type erases down to

1. Invoke with `Sig`
2. Destroy
3. Copy (and sometimes move)
4. Cast-back-to-original-type

Your lambda cannot be copied, so cannot be stored in a `std::function`.

The lazy-coder's solution is:

```
    dispatch([bar2 = std::make_shared<decltype(bar)>(std::move(bar)), &foo]() mutable {
        foo = std::move(*bar2);
    });
```

where we shove the non-copyable state into a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Oh, my bad, you are right, the problem is not the lambda being `mutable`! I have updated the title of my question a little bit so it at least makes sense. So your solution is based on storing the `unique_ptr` inside a `shared_ptr`, which can be copied. Did I understand it correctly? Does the `std::move(*bar2)` prevent unnecessary copying of the `bar` object? Are there are problems with this solution? Thanks!

Comment: @TomsonTom I don't understand the question.  Are you asking if `std::move` copies?  Sure there are problems, your `function` shares its `bar2` state with all copies of itself.  `dispatch` should really take either a move-only function type-erasure object, or if it is synchronous it should take a function-view type-erasure object.  But you have to code around bad APIs some time.

Comment: Thanks, I have decided to accept your answer as it helped me understand the problems. I am using [asio](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio) and I have just found out that this is [a common problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211263/how-to-trick-boostasio-to-allow-move-only-handlers/) and people are doing [nasty tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211263/how-to-trick-boostasio-to-allow-move-only-handlers/22891509#22891509) to compile their codes with unique pointers.