# Generic thread pool class is not working properly

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, lambda, threadpool

I am trying to make a thread pool class which receives several functions and put them into the queue until they finish and then I can add another function to take advantage of the created threads instead of creating them when I want to run other functions. That's why I include a conditional variable to synchonize all the threads.

However, the code is not working properly because somehow when the function is invoked the object makes a copy. After several tries, I can not figure out what I am missing!

What I expect is that member function `greetings` of the `hw` object execute in parallel whit his index. But when the line `(o.*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);` is executed the object is copied, although the copy constructor is deleted. So when it enters into the `greetings` member it produces a `SEGMENTATION FAULT`.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(boost_asyo LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(boost_asyo main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} boost_thread boost_system)
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <memory>

#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

class Semaphore
{
    std::mutex lock;

    std::condition_variable cond;

    int count;

public:

    Semaphore()
    {
        count = 0;
    }

    void wait()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> m(lock);

        while(count > 0)
            cond.wait(m, [this]{ return count == 0; });
    }

    void take()
    {
        std::unique_lock m(lock);

        count++;
    }

    void give()
    {
        std::unique_lock m(lock);

        count--;

        if(count == 0)
        {
            cond.notify_one();
        }
    }
};


class ThreadPool
{
private:
    boost::asio::io_service m_io_service;
    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> m_work;
    boost::thread_group m_threads;
    Semaphore m_sem;

public:
    ThreadPool(size_t n)
    {
        this->m_work = std::make_unique<boost::asio::io_service::work>(m_io_service);

        for (size_t ii = 0; ii < n; ii++)
        {
            m_threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &this->m_io_service));
        }
    }

    ThreadPool(const ThreadPool & v) = delete;
    ThreadPool(ThreadPool && v) = delete;

    ~ThreadPool()
    {
        m_io_service.stop();
    }

    template<class type, class T, class T1, class... Args>
    auto post(type T::*f, T1 &obj, Args... args)
    {
        this->m_sem.take();
        this->m_io_service.post([&] ()
        {
            T o = static_cast<T&&>(obj);

            (o.*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            this->m_sem.give();
        });

    }

    void wait()
    {
        this->m_sem.wait();
    }
};

class HelloWorld
{
private:

public:
    std::string m_str;
    HelloWorld(std::string str) : m_str(str) {};
    HelloWorld(const HelloWorld& v) = delete;
    HelloWorld(HelloWorld&& v) = default;

    ~HelloWorld() = default;

    void greetings(int ii)
    {
        for (int jj = 0; jj < 5; jj++)
        {
            std::cout << this->m_str << " " << ii <<  std::endl;

            boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(1));
        }

    }
};


int main()
{
    ThreadPool tp(8);

    HelloWorld hw("Hola mundo");

    for (int ii = 0; ii < 5; ii++)
    {
        tp.post(&HelloWorld::greetings, hw, ii);
    }

    tp.wait();

    return 0;
}
```

This code is based on this one, which it works properly, and this is something similar to what I want to do with classes and members.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <memory>

#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

class Semaphore
{
    std::mutex lock;

    std::condition_variable cond;

    int count;

public:

    Semaphore()
    {
        count = 0;
    }

    void wait()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> m(lock);

        while(count > 0)
            cond.wait(m, [this]{ return count == 0; });
    }

    void take()
    {
        std::unique_lock m(lock);

        count++;
    }

    void give()
    {
        std::unique_lock m(lock);

        count--;

        if(count == 0)
        {
            cond.notify_one();
        }
    }
};


int main()
{    
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> work = std::make_unique<boost::asio::io_service::work>(io_service);

    boost::thread_group threads;

    for (size_t ii = 0; ii < 2; ii++)
    {
        std::cout << "id: " << ii << std::endl;
        threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
    }

    Semaphore sem;

    for (size_t ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++)
    {
        //Take
        sem.take();

        io_service.post([ii, &sem] ()
        {
            int id = 0;
            while(id < 5)
            {
                id++;
                printf("hello world %i\n", static_cast<int>(ii));
                boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(1));
            }

            //Give
            sem.give();
        });
    }


    sem.wait();


    for (size_t ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++)
    {
        sem.take();

        io_service.post([ii, &sem] ()
        {
            int id = 0;
            while(id < 5)
            {
                id++;
                printf("bye world %i\n", static_cast<int>(ii));
                boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(1));
            }
            sem.give();
        });
    }

    sem.wait();

    io_service.stop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what function makes a copy? What is the output / expected output?

Comment: Yes, You are right. I edited my question to give more details. What I expect is that the member functions run in parallel with the ThreadPool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really curious what the semaphore is about.

`io_service` is already a task queue. It's thread safe and you don't need a semaphore.

> For comparison, here's io_service based thread pool:
>
> - A thread pool like yours, without Asio, using a condition variable in much the same way but without calling it "semaphore"
>   [boost thread throwing exception "thread_resource_error: resource temporarily unavailable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569805/boost-thread-throwing-exception-thread-resource-error-resource-temporarily-una/22570554#22570554)
> - The same thing, but rewritten around `io_service` like your ThreadPool, which shows how you don't need the semaphore anymore
>   [**Solution 1**] in
>   [c++ work queues with blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925256/c-work-queues-with-blocking/25928221#25928221)
>   (Solution 2 is using the same threadpool as before).
>
> (Even better, recent Asio versions have a built-in thread-pool).

### Where Is The Error

This is unsafe:

```
template <class type, class T, class T1, class... Args>
auto post(type T::*f, T1& obj, Args... args) {
    this->m_sem.take();
    this->m_io_service.post([&]() {
        T o = static_cast<T&&>(obj);
        (o.*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        this->m_sem.give();
    });
}
```

Specifically:

0. The line

   ```
   T o = static_cast<T&&>(obj);
   ```

   doesn't copy T (which is `HelloWorld`). You knew that because that wouldn't be possible. What happens is WORSE: the object is MOVED from `obj`.

   > Incidentally, this assumes that T is move-constructible from T1.

   You specifically ask for it by explicitly casting the right-handside to an rvalue-reference.

   > This is what `std::move` is specified to do, actually: *["In particular, std::move produces an xvalue expression that identifies its argument t. It is exactly equivalent to a static_cast to an rvalue reference type."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move)*

   The effect is that the HelloWorld instance in `main` is no longer valid, yet you keep moving from it for subsequent tasks.
1. The other arguments captured **by reference**. This means they're out of scope before the task actually executes (including `f`).

To make this safe, you have had to capture the arguments in local copies:

```
template <class type, class T, class... Args>
auto post(type T::*f, T&& obj, Args... args) {
    this->m_sem.take();
    this->m_io_service.post([=, o = std::move(obj)]() mutable {
        try {
            (o.*f)(args...);
        } catch (...) {
            this->m_sem.give();
            throw;
        }
        this->m_sem.give();
    });
}
```

Notes:

0. now `obj` is taken by *rvalue* reference. This means that `post` won't compile unless `obj` is an rvalue.

   > Note this is not a *[universal reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39552345/85371)* because `T` is deduced as part of `f`.
1. the lambda is now mutable (because otherwise only `const` member functions could be run on the captured `o`)
2. all other args are copied - this is roughly how `std::bind` would operate, but you could optimize for movable arguments).
3. We handle exceptions - in your code if `f` threw, you would never `give()` the semaphore

Of course, `main` needs to adapt so multiple `HelloWorld` instances are actually created and passed by rvalue:

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < 5; ii++) {
    HelloWorld hw("Hola mundo");
    tp.post(&HelloWorld::greetings, std::move(hw), ii);
}
```

### BUT - IT WON'T WORK

At least, for me it doesn't compile. Asio requires handlers to be copyable ([why must a Boost.Asio handler be copy constructible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709819/why-must-a-boost-asio-handler-be-copy-constructible/37795582#37795582), [How to trick boost::asio to allow move-only handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211263/how-to-trick-boostasio-to-allow-move-only-handlers/22891509#22891509)).

Also, we hardly scratched the surface. By hardcoding for `type T::*f` you made it so that you need new `post` overloads for many things: static methods, `const` member functions ...

Instead, why not do it the C++ way:

```
template <class F, class... Args>
auto post(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    this->m_sem.take();
    this->m_io_service.post(
        [this, f=std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...)] 
        {
            try { f(); }
            catch (...) {
                this->m_sem.give();
                throw;
            }
            this->m_sem.give();
        });
}
```

Actually, in more modern C++ you'd write (assuming c++17 here):

```
    //...
        [this, f=std::forward<F>(f), args=std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)] 
        {
            try { std::apply(f, args); }
    //...
```

> Oh, and we still need
>
> ```
> #define BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_HANDLER_TYPE_REQUIREMENTS 1
> ```
>
> because of the move-only handler type

### Full Fixed Version Demo

> NOTE: Also added an output mutex (`s_outputmx`) to avoid intermixed console output.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f4a3b11b814a575)**

```
#define BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_HANDLER_TYPE_REQUIREMENTS 1
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <memory>

#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

class Semaphore {
    std::mutex lock;
    std::condition_variable cond;
    int count;
  public:
    Semaphore() { count = 0; }
    void wait() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> m(lock);
        while (count > 0)
            cond.wait(m, [this] { return count == 0; });
    }
    void take() {
        std::unique_lock m(lock);
        count++;
    }
    void give() {
        std::unique_lock m(lock);
        count--;
        if (count == 0) {
            cond.notify_one();
        }
    }
};


class ThreadPool {
  private:
    boost::asio::io_service m_io_service;
    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> m_work;
    boost::thread_group m_threads;
    Semaphore m_sem;

  public:
    ThreadPool(size_t n) {
        this->m_work =
            std::make_unique<boost::asio::io_service::work>(m_io_service);
        for (size_t ii = 0; ii < n; ii++) {
            m_threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run,
                                                &this->m_io_service));
        }
    }
    ThreadPool(const ThreadPool& v) = delete;
    ThreadPool(ThreadPool&& v) = delete;
    ~ThreadPool() { m_io_service.stop(); }

    template <class F, class... Args>
    auto post(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
        this->m_sem.take();
        this->m_io_service.post(
#if 1 // pre-c++17
            [this, f=std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...)] 
            {
                try { f(); }
#else // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply
            [this, f=std::forward<F>(f), args=std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)] 
            {
                try { std::apply(f, args); }
#endif
                catch (...) {
                    this->m_sem.give();
                    throw;
                }
                this->m_sem.give();
            });
    }


    void wait() { this->m_sem.wait(); }
};

struct HelloWorld {
    std::string m_str;

    HelloWorld(std::string str) : m_str(str){};
    HelloWorld(const HelloWorld& v) = delete;
    HelloWorld(HelloWorld&& v) = default;
    ~HelloWorld() = default;

    void greetings(int ii) const {
        for (int jj = 0; jj < 5; jj++) {
            {
                static std::mutex s_outputmx;
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(s_outputmx);
                std::cout << this->m_str << " " << ii << std::endl;
            }
            boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(1));
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    ThreadPool tp(8);

    for (int ii = 0; ii < 5; ii++) {
        HelloWorld hw("Hola mundo");
        tp.post(&HelloWorld::greetings, std::move(hw), ii);
    }

    tp.wait();
}
```

Prints

```
Hola mundo 0
Hola mundo 2
Hola mundo 3
Hola mundo 1
Hola mundo 4
Hola mundo 0
Hola mundo 1
Hola mundo 4
Hola mundo 2
Hola mundo 3
Hola mundo 0
Hola mundo 1
Hola mundo 4
Hola mundo 2
Hola mundo 3
Hola mundo 0
Hola mundo 4
Hola mundo 2
Hola mundo 3
Hola mundo 1
Hola mundo 0
Hola mundo 4
Hola mundo 2
Hola mundo 1
Hola mundo 3
```

### BONUS: Drop semaphore

Dropping the semaphore and actually using `work`:

```
class ThreadPool {
    boost::asio::io_service m_io_service;
    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> m_work;
    boost::thread_group m_threads;

  public:
    ThreadPool(size_t n)
        : m_work(std::make_unique<boost::asio::io_service::work>(m_io_service))
    {
        while (n--) {
            m_threads.create_thread([this] { m_io_service.run(); });
        }
    }

    ~ThreadPool() { wait(); }

    void wait() {
        m_work.reset();
        m_threads.join_all();
    }

    template <class F, class... Args> void post(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
        m_io_service.post(
            [f=std::forward<F>(f), args=std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)] {
                std::apply(f, args); 
            });
    }
};
```

That's 28 lines of code, compared to 90 lines in your original. And it actually does *more things*.

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73df3a368c11af85)** as well.

### What's Left?

We didn't handle exceptions from `io_service::run` properly (see [Should the exception thrown by boost::asio::io_service::run() be caught?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500818/should-the-exception-thrown-by-boostasioio-servicerun-be-caught/44500924#44500924))

Also, if you have "recent" Boost, you can enjoy an improved interface to `work` (`make_work_guard` and `.reset()` so you don't need `unique_ptr`), and a ready-made `thread_pool` (so you don't need ... basically anything anymore):

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14dcf3a9dca7867e)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
static std::mutex s_outputmx;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

struct HelloWorld {
    std::string const m_str;
    void greetings(int ii) const;
};

int main() {
    boost::asio::thread_pool tp(8);

    for (int ii = 0; ii < 5; ii++)
        //post(tp, [hw=HelloWorld{"Hola mundo"}, ii] { hw.greetings(ii); });
        post(tp, std::bind(&HelloWorld::greetings, HelloWorld{"Hola mundo"}, ii));

    tp.join();
}

void HelloWorld::greetings(int ii) const {
    for (int jj = 0; jj < 5; jj++) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(s_outputmx);
        std::cout << m_str << " " << ii << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Added some bonus takes and live demos, including one that fixes all the issues and fits the whole thing <30 lines of code (with the includes)

Comment: A lot of thanks @sehe. I appreciate your answer, it is very useful. The semaphore class aimed to synchronize the threads without stopping the 'io_service', so they could be used later. One more question, in your last script, I am not able to post additional functions to the thread_pool anymore. Is there a way to reuse the thread_pool after calling `tp.join()`?

Comment: @dangulo https://stackoverflow.com/a/62399256/85371